# How do I permanently change a Pandas column with to_datetime so I can write to a .json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

Python 3.9, Pandas 1.3.0 on Win 10

Hi,

I have a DataFrame (df), where two of the columns contain Unix timestamps (columns 0 and 6, '**open time**' and '**close time**').

> ```
>           open time    open    high  ...       volume     close time  number of trades
>    0  1609459200000  736.42  739.00  ...  27932.69884  1609462799999             22671
>    1  1609462800000  734.08  749.00  ...  52336.18779  1609466399999             41712
> ```

I reformat these to dtype = datetime64 with the following code:

```
df.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df['open time'], unit='ms')
df.iloc[:,6] = pd.to_datetime(df['close time'], unit='ms')
```

The result is what I wanted, datetime with ms precision, as viewed with **df.head()**

> ```
>                open time    open  ...              close time  number of trades
>    0 2021-01-01 00:00:00  736.42  ... 2021-01-01 00:59:59.999             22671
>    1 2021-01-01 01:00:00  734.08  ... 2021-01-01 01:59:59.999             41712
> ```

When I write this to a json file however, the changes aren't saved.

```
df.to_json("ETHUSDT_out_hist1.json", orient="records", indent=2)
```

resulting .json file content - Unix timestamps are still present:

```
{"open time":1609459200000,
 "open":736.42,
  // 1, 2, skip a few
 "close time":1609462799999,
 "number of trades":22671}
```

I suspect that I created a copy by applying the *to_datetime* method instead of changing the original df object.

My question is, how do I change the orginal object / DataFrame so my changes will save to the json file? There is no inplace parameter for to_datetime, and I can't seem to figure out how to assign the changes back to the original df.
A few hours trawling SO, the Pandas docs and other fora have not resulted in a working solution either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Pandas documentation, to_json converts the timestamp to UNIX https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html?highlight=to_json, so either convert from UNIX back to timestamp when you process the json, or convert to string.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'open time':[1609459200000, 1609462800000],'close time':[1609462799999, 1609466399999]})

df['open time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['open time'], unit='ms').astype(str)
df['close time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['close time'], unit='ms').astype(str)

df.to_json("ETHUSDT_out_hist1.json", orient="records") # , indent=2)
```

to get json:

```
{"open time":{"0":"2021-01-01 00:00:00","1":"2021-01-01 01:00:00"},"close time":{"0":"2021-01-01 00:59:59.999","1":"2021-01-01 01:59:59.999"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, converting back to string worked and in hindsight I could have thought of this myself. It turns out I do need to keep the 'orient = "records" parameter, otherwise it writes all of column 0 first, then column 1, &c. --> I need nice records.

Comment: Terrific, I edited my answer to use the records.  Can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying type is persisted in JSON as long int. In order to see values like: `2021-01-01 00:00:00` you would have to cast it to string:

```
df['open time'] = df['open time'].apply(str, axis=1)
df['open time'] = df['close time'].apply(str, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've done all your data types conversions, use the `data_format='iso'` parameter when writing the data frame to a json file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'open time':[1609459200000, 1609462800000],'close time':[1609462799999, 1609466399999]})

df['open time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['open time'], unit='ms')
df['close time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['close time'], unit='ms') 
df.to_json("out_hist1.json", date_format='iso', orient='records')
```

see how data types are maintained in the df, no need to change them to srings before saving to file:

```
print(df.dtypes) 

>> output >>

Output menu
open time     datetime64[ns]
close time    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

and it is maintaining the orientation by record in the output file:

```
%%bash
head out_hist1.json

[
{"open time":"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","close time":"2021-01-01T00:59:59.999Z"},
{"open time":"2021-01-01T01:00:00.000Z","close time":"2021-01-01T01:59:59.999Z"}
]
```